# How to get user object to send pm

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Im currently working on an discord.js bot and my problem is that I want to send a private message to an specific user whos connected to the server.

I want to do something like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41745070/discord-js-sending-private-messages-to-user) thread answered. The goal is to use this:

```
message.author.sendMessage("Your message here.")
```

but except for .author i want to send it to an other client on the server, so I thought I have to get an user object or something like this...

I hope someone can help me. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I saw your code, I can safely assume that you know how to PM a user with your bot. So I will only explain the part of getting the user.

If say you want to message the user whenever a new user connects to a server, there is a `guildMemberAdd` eventhandler.

```
client.on("guildMemberAdd", user => {
//stuff here
})
```

The `user` in that handler is a `GuildMember` object.

Now from there. If you want to inform the server's owner that someone joined, simply do `user.guild.owner` and it will return another `GuildMember` object which contains the properties of the server's owner.

Just check out the docs about `client` object [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client), you will be able to see the list of eventHandlers.