# How do I get BOT to create a private chat? (Discord.js)

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm trying to create a command in which BOT creates a private chat that only the user,the BOT and I have access to, but I don't know how I do it, I've read the docs but I couldn't. Please, I really need this code Version of my Discord.js: 12.3.1 Structure I use to create a command:

```js
if (comando === "command") {
//code
}
```

Comment: This might be able to help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41745070/sending-private-messages-to-user

Comment: @E3saR, It's not to send the author's DM, but to create a chat inside my server that only the author, me and BOT can see, 
I think I'll add that to my question

Comment: Stack Overflow won’t write your entire solution *for* you, regardless of how much you “*really need this code*”. Edit your question to show *exactly* what you’ve tried so far, and where *specifically* in those attempts you’re getting stuck; “*I don’t know how I do it*” isn’t a valid problem statement and doesn’t at all describe the problems you’re encountering that we can help with. Revisit [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for a refresher on Stack Overflow’s asking guidelines.

Comment: Please do not use a stack snippet for code that isn't runnable. Stack snippets are only meant for HTML, CSS, and JavaScript code that can be run on a browser. Please format your code using a [code block](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361/8289918) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To let the bot be able to create a new channel**

```js
const bot = new Discord.Client();

function makeChannel(message){
    var server = message.guild;
    var name = message.author.username;

    server.createChannel(name, "text");
}
```

**And here you have a whole list of functions that can be very usefull in your use case**

```js
client.on('message', message => {
    // Getting member permission
    message.member.hasPermission('SEND_MESSAGES');
    message.member.hasPermissions(['SEND_MESSAGES', 'ADD_REACTIONS']);

    // Getting channel-wide user permissions
    message.member.permissionIn('channel_id').hasPermission('SEND_MESSAGES');
    message.member.permissionIn('channel_id').hasPermissions(['SEND_MESSAGES', 'ADD_REACTIONS']);

    // Setting channel-wide user permissions
    message.channel.overwritePermissions('user_id', { SEND_MESSAGES: true, ADD_REACTIONS: false});


    // Getting channel-wide role permissions
    /* Alright, this is a little more complicated because there's no
        built-in method for it.
        You can make one using the following:
    */
        message.channel.permissionOverwrites.get('role_id').allow;
        message.channel.permissionOverwrites.get('role_id').deny;

    // Setting channel-wide role permissions
    message.channel.overwritePermissions('role_id', { SEND_MESSAGES: true, ADD_REACTIONS: false});


    // Getting server-wide role permissions
    message.guild.roles.get('rold_id').hasPermission('SEND_MESSAGES');
    message.guild.roles.get('rold_id').hasPermissions(['SEND_MESSAGES', 'ADD_REACTIONS']);

    // Setting server-wide role permissions
    message.guild.roles.get('role_id').setPermissions([SEND_MESSAGES: true, ADD_REACTIONS: false]);
});

/* List of permissions, directly taken from the Discord.js code
ADMINISTRATOR
CREATE_INSTANT_INVITE
KICK_MEMBERS
BAN_MEMBERS
MANAGE_CHANNELS
MANAGE_GUILD
ADD_REACTIONS
VIEW_AUDIT_LOG
VIEW_CHANNEL
READ_MESSAGES
SEND_MESSAGES
SEND_TTS_MESSAGES
MANAGE_MESSAGES
EMBED_LINKS
ATTACH_FILES
READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY
MENTION_EVERYONE
USE_EXTERNAL_EMOJIS
EXTERNAL_EMOJIS
CONNECT // Voice Channel
SPEAK
MUTE_MEMBERS
DEAFEN_MEMBERS
MOVE_MEMBERS
USE_VAD // Voice Auto Detection
CHANGE_NICKNAME
MANAGE_NICKNAMES
MANAGE_ROLES
MANAGE_ROLES_OR_PERMISSIONS
MANAGE_WEBHOOKS
MANAGE_EMOJIS
*/
```