# Discord Bot NodeJs

Tags: node.js

I'm currently writing an Discord Bot and it's supposed to interact with a person who just got "online". I would like to know how I can get my bot to interact with someone who just logged into discord (I know their username and ID).

I'm sure what I have rn is completly wrong but it's a start.

```
module.exports = {
name: 'name',
async execute(interaction) {
await interaction.reply("Your tag:" + {
interaction.client.clientID)
    },
};
```

Comment: And what exactly is your question?

Comment: I would like to know how I can get my bot to interact with someone who just logged in to discord- I know their Username and ID - 
seems like I'm just too dumb today to figure this out

Comment: No-one is dumb, just not clued up yet, I guess you should start by reading the official [discord docs](https://discord.com/developers/docs/intro).. I'd also suggest to edit your question to include more details of what exactly you are trying to achieve and also what you have tried/looked into already and any possible errors/issues you might have encountered. Similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65907166/use-discord-api-to-send-a-private-message-given-a-user-id or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41745070/sending-private-messages-to-user

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.