# how do i make my bot show the name of the discord server in which the command was used

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am trying to make a command that bans a user when they say a blacklisted word and I am trying to figure out how to make it dm them the server they were banned in. For example,

````js
if (message.content == `nword`) {
  message.author.send(`You were banned from (The server they were banned from) for saying the n-word`)
  member.ban()
}```
````

Comment: What’s the question exactly? Can you edit your question to include a clear problem statement, along with what you’ve tried before posting here to satisfy this requirement?

Answer (score 1):

You've got the message sending part correct, see here for the discussion: [Sending private messages to user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41745070/sending-private-messages-to-user)

You can access the `guild` property of a message, and add the guild's name to your DM message. https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/Message?scrollTo=guild

That would be an instance of the guild class, which has a lot of properties including `name` which is probably what you're after. https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=name

An example implementation, untested:

```js
let serverName = message.guild.name;
message.author.send("You were banned from " + serverName + "for saying...");
```