# Is there a way to make my bot always dm me when a command is used?

Tags: javascript, discord.js, command

Like for example, I want to make my bot dm me whenever my command for example I'm making a "Suggestion" command
so whenever someone does for example w!suggest "Their suggestion for my bot" the bot dms me with the suggestion so far I have

so whenever someone uses the command it dms me the developer the "suggestion" in the code which is whatever they suggest

```js
const suggestsomething = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
         .setAuthor(message.author.tag, message.author.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true }))
         .setColor(message.guild.me.displayColor)
         .setDescription("Suggest something don't leave it empty.")
         .setTimestamp()
        if(!args[0]) return message.channel.send(suggestsomething)
        const suggestion = args.join(" ");
```

Comment: "*Is there a way to make my bot always dm me when a command is used?*" There sure is. What code have you written to try to meet this requirement? Stack Overflow won't write it for you, but we can help if you share a [mre] of the code that's supposed to carry out this task, along with a succinct explanation of where you're getting stuck in the attempt. [ask]

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest doing a little research yourself before asking it right away. A simple google search and I came up with this:

Take a look at this [stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58439049/11943314).

```
client.users.fetch('USER ID', false).then((user) => {
 user.send('hello world');
});
```

If you don't know how to obtain your user id, take a look [here](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/206346498-Where-can-I-find-my-User-Server-Message-ID-).