# Sending a message to a specific user

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, bots

I have this code: I want the bot to send the message every 1 minute to a user not to send every 1 minute to all users

```
  guild.members.cache.forEach(member => {
 setInterval(() => {
      member.send('hello').catch(error => {message.channel.send(`**dm closed**`)});
   }, 60000)
  })
   }) 
  }
})
```

I want the bot to send the message every 1 minute to a specific user, not all.

I tried the code below, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sending private messages to user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41745070/sending-private-messages-to-user)

Comment: You're sending to every user because you're taking the guild members and looping over every single one with [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

Comment: No i need to send to all users in server but i need the bot to send every 1 minute the message to a user

Comment: Why do you create [accounts](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20607609/tompano) after [accounts](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20705142/hussein-awada) to ask the same question? Your [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74697302/sending-a-message-to-user-every-1-minute) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74706501/i-need-the-bot-to-send-a-message-every-1-minute-to-a-user) are closed because your question doesn't include enough details to answer it correctly.

Answer (score -1):

So, for what I understood, for every member on a list, you want to send a message to each one one minute separated from each other.

You can use one interval for all members, saving on memory usage and CPU usage, by keeping a reference to the index of the last member that was sent a message.

```
let members = guild.members.cache
let index = -1;
let timer = setInterval(() => {
    if (index + 1 >= members.length) index = 0;
    else index++;
    
    let member = members[index];
    if (member) member.send('hello').catch(error => {message.channel.send(`**dm closed**`)});
}, 60000)
```

Comment: Yes i want the bot to send every 1 minute to a user the message i tried your code but not working its giving me an error undefined .send

Answer (score -2):

Form the looks of it looks like you are looping through a list of guild members and for each member int that list you are sending 'hello' every minute.
If you want to send 'hello' to a specific user every minute you have to specify a member in below code(replace specificMember with that member)

```
 setInterval(() => {
   specificMember.send('hello')
   .catch(error => {message.channel.send(`**dm closed**`)});
 }, 60000)
```

Comment: No i want the bot to send the message to a user every 1 minute not all users and not 1 user all the users in my server